# Wake up android app via push notification while in doze without FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, doze

Greatings!

We are developing an android app with Xamarin that has to meet the following restrictions:

- wifi yes, but no internet connection
- no FCM/google play services  (app should also work in China)
- push messages from a Manager-SW (uses rabbitmq) need to arrive quickly after being send (< 1min) AND also when the device is in doze mode
- no pulling mechanism

At the moment we are having a wifilock and a wakelock. The battery optimization for this app is turned off. This way messages always arrive even when the device goes to doze mode.. with some exceptions.
There are devices like the HUAWEI P20 that have their own battery save solution (App launch) --> app is not running although we have all the stuff above

Also this solution is not ideal considering battery usage.

I have looked into alternatvies like Pushy, but for me it seems they have problems with doze mode too.

Do you know any alternatives to FCM?

Is there any easy way to go around the Huawei stuff without the user having to change the settings manually?

Many thanks to all of you in advance!

Comment: Did you solve this issue? We are facing the same.

Comment: same here, did you solve it? @JanNepraš